Nested sliding problem between MotionLayout and RecyclerView
The RecyclerView component is nested in the MotionLayout. When sliding back and forth quickly, there will be a problem of staying in the middle of the animation, even though my settings are as follows
 <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:onTouchUp="autoComplete"
            motion:touchRegionId="@id/rv_list"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/rv_list" />    

In fact, sometimes the animation is not completed, and this is very easy to be triggered
      @Override
      public void onStopNestedScroll(@NonNull View target, int type) {
         if (DEBUG) {
            Log.v(TAG, "********** onStopNestedScroll(   target:"
                    + Debug.getName(target) + " , type:" + type + " "
                    + mScrollTargetDX + ", " + mScrollTargetDY);
            Debug.logStack(TAG, "onStopNestedScroll ", 8);

         }
         if (mScene == null || mScrollTargetDT == 0) {
            Log.v(TAG, "********** onStopNestedScroll(  mScene == " +mScene +" || mScrollTargetDT     == "+mScrollTargetDT+")");
            return;
         }
         mScene.processScrollUp(mScrollTargetDX / mScrollTargetDT,
                mScrollTargetDY / mScrollTargetDT);
    }

It can be seen that after onNestedScrollAccepted assigns mScrollTargetDT to 0, it does not take the rest of the steps, and after judging it to 0, it directly returns the method, so it cannot continue to execute.
I downloaded the source code and tried to modify it. If the execution continues when mScrollTargetDT is 0, the animation will freeze.
